# Is it possible to compile nodejs project into single javascript file?

Tags: node.js

The difficulty I see is with all the require calls, and the dependency tree. Is there a way to iterate through a project, including dependencies where needed, and produce a single, fully contained javascript file?

I am hoping to convert some server side only libraries to client side apps.

Alternatively, is there another method to achieve this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is a file `lib/_third_party_main.js` in the node source when you compile, it will run that on start. See [src/node.js](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/feaa8a41c7533c254923ea7333457234ed44f8f9/src/node.js#L55L61). You might be able to compile your sources with e.g. [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) or [Google Closure](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/).

**Edit:** Also, you can `require` any modules you put in `lib` as if they were native modules. Example:

## lib/_third_party_main.js

```
var foo = require('foo');

foo();
```

## lib/foo.js

```
module.exports = function() {
  console.log('O hai');
}
```

Compile and run, and it will print `O hai`.

**Edit:** You might be able to use [Ender.js](http://ender.no.de/), [Browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify) or a similar browser packaging tool to build a single file.

Comment: This looks like all the information I wanted. I think browserify is what I was after (although I am having trouble installing via npm). I will check all the links you have given me. Thanks ,~)